# How to correctly write meson syntax?

Tags: syntax, cairo, meson-build

I'm trying to compile cairo libraries from sources partially using meson

The part of the script that is crashing in the meson.build script look like that:

```
cairo_feature_sources = {
  'cairo-png': [
    'cairo-png.c',
  ],

...
...
...

  'cairo-tee': [
    'cairo-tee-surface.c',
  ],
}
```

when I launch "meson setup" I receive this error:

```
meson.build:127:23: ERROR: lexer
cairo_feature_sources = {
                       ^
```

Could someone point where the problem is?

Comment: my guess is that it's due to a line above your pasted not being ended properly and Meson choking on that

Answer (score 1):

Most probable explanation could be that you are trying to build with old meson version (older than 0.47.0) since support for dictionaries (syntax construction with *name = {'key': val, ...}*) [was added to 0.47.0](https://mesonbuild.com/Syntax.html#dictionaries).

The build should've failed immediately saying that version is not compatible since e.g. currently cairo has the following minimum version:

```
project('cairo', 'c', 'cpp',
  meson_version: '>= 0.56.0',
```

However, if this piece was back-ported (or copied) inaccurately from newer to older cairo this could have happen.

Answer (score 0):

I've downloaded latest meson from the official website, however I was building at the 18.04 Bionic

After I've upgrade distro to 20.04.2 everything is running smooth, so I guess there was some kind of incompatibility between new meson and the old distro libs